# <#list> array ob objects in FTL [how to]

Tags: freemarker

Hez guys,
lets imagine we have array of objects like one below, so key + value always same

```
<#assign h =  [
    {
      "code": "B1",
      "desc": "3-DESC HERE
    }
    {
      "code": "B2",
      "desc": "4-DESC HERE"
    }
  ]>
```

Is there some nice way to <#list> this and nicely just display data like:

```
${code} ${desc}
```

What i found but I think its just overkill for this kind of situation

```
<#list h?keys as key>
${key} = ${modelOptions[key]};
</#list>
```

I will be happy for any advise

Comment: Why do you think this is overkill? Freemarker is very verbose :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<#list h as item>
${item.code} = ${item.desc}
</#list>
```

Comment: This throw me error, I belieave its because its array of objects not just object :)